# Best Practices for Refactoring Test Code

Tags: refactoring, automated-tests

I currently have a job in QA and at my company everyone in QA writes automated tests. Recently I have been reading [Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485672) by Martin Fowler. I have come to realize that a lot of our test classes and test utilities are very messy, redundant, and in dire need of refactoring.

Especially since I've been reading up on the topic, I am eager to dive in and clean things up, but there is one problem. In his book, Fowler emphasizes that unit testing the code under refactor is essential to prevent bugs from being introduced. Since the code I am trying to refactor is test code, it seems kind of silly to unit test it. Do any of you guys have suggestions on how to refactor or even design test code? Also, if it helps, the test framework we use is built on top of JUnit and therefore the test classes I'm referring to are descendants of TestCase.

Thanks!

Comment: Regarding your first statement. I think a common misconception in the red, green, refactor cycle is that the refactor is only on your code under test. A very important part of writing maintainable tests is to ensure that you refactor your tests as part of the refactor cycle keeping DRY in mind. The first refactor I always do after testing the contructor is to extract a factory method to create the object under test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope that's not entirely correct. The trick to re factoring is to be able to verify that you've kept the functionality.

You need to make sure that that all changes are verified before and after. There's not really away around this. However you don't need to write automated tests for that code but it may help.

The trick with complex refactoring of test code is to be able to run the tests against the system under test and get the same results.

So in fact the verifiability is making sure that the output is the same. This should be automated. You can do this in many ways but the simplest would be to output the test you're running with the data you're testing with together with output you expect and the output you receive.

Possibly you can use some machine readable format like XML to make is easier to parse.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous post that you should run your test suite before and after you modify the suite implementation to verify that it functions the same.

You can also unit test code that implements unit tests with an even simpler unit test framework.  If your code inherits from JUnit then use JUnit to test it.  At a minimum you have to assume that JUnit works.